# SQL query to LINQ expression - Entity Core Framework 3 + SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core, fluent

```
DECLARE @thirtyDaysAgo DATETIME = getdate()-30

SELECT 
sum(case when CreatedWhen >= @thirtyDaysAgo then 1 else 0 end) lessThan30,
sum(case when CreatedWhen < @thirtyDaysAgo then 1 else 0 end) Greaterthan30
FROM ThisAwesomeTable
```

Cannot figure out how to convert this to a fluent query.

The intent is to count the number of rows that were created more than 30 days ago and also count the number of rows that were created within the last 30 days **in the same query.**

Comment: This sort of query doesn't translate to LINQ well. There are some things better left in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the singleton `GroupBy` trick:

```
var ans = ThisAwesomeTable.GroupBy(r => 1)
                          .Select(rg => new {
                              lessThan30 = rg.Sum(r => r.CreatedWhen >= thirtyDaysAgo ? 1 : 0),
                              GreaterThan30 = rg.Sum(r => r.CreatedWhen < thirtyDaysAgo ? 1 : 0)
                          });
```

Note that EF Core 3 generates exactly the same SQL as listed for this query.